# symfony2 server design pattern best practice

Tags: rest, symfony, titanium, client, server

So I'm about to create a mobile application using titanium. I want to use Symfony2 as the server and communicate via rest API's with the client (mobile)

What I am asking is what are the best practices when it comes to designing my server? and what do you recommend I start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) or the [Symfony REST Edition](https://github.com/gimler/symfony-rest-edition), this should get you started quickly.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle

https://github.com/gimler/symfony-rest-edition

Comment: https://github.com/voryx/restgeneratorbundle This in addition to the ones you mentioned helped me get started

Answer (score 2):

As far as RESTful API endpoint design and the data your API will transfer, I really like this guide:

http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Granted, this is more of a generic "How do I REST API?" guide, but I think it's useful in a situation like yours.